# Angular 2 - Best approach to clone BlogComponent:blogs[] to Navmenu combobox?

Tags: angular

The case is that i want to have an combobox (select) in `NavMenuComponent` with blogs. Its about fast navigation experience.

Currently i have second array `blogs: IBlogs[]` which is bad practitce but anyway.

My problem now is that when i add/delete any blog combobox is not getting updated. And thats because im working with `BlogComponent>blogs[]` and not `NavMenuComponent>blogs[]`

I must hard refresh to get it work! any better approach? can i force update of array from another component? [without shared service]

I could put them into shared service but i don't like the idea. Because then in `BlogComponent` i will have to use `sharedService.getBlogs()` instead of `blogService.getBlogs()`.

Any idea?

Comment: Personally I prefer `sharedBlogService` but whatever... In component that CREATES/DELETES `blog`, add `Observable`s and emit event whenever change happens, then in `NavMenuComponent` listen to that event.

Comment: Any link? im new to angular

Answer (score 0):

As example:

```
export enum BlogAction{
    CREATE,
    DELETE
}

export Blog{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export class BlogActionModel{
    action: BlogAction;
    blog: Blog;
}

@Injectable()
export class BlogService{

    private blogPoster: Subject<BlogActionModel> = new Subject<BlogActionModel>();
    public $blogPosted: Observable<BlogActionModel> = this.blogPoster.asObservable();

    create(blog: Blog): void{
        this.blogResource.saveToBackend(blog); //do save routine
        this.blogPoster.next({
            action: BlogAction.CREATE,
            blog: blog
        });
    }

    //implement `update` and `delete` actions in same way
}

@Component({})
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit{

    private blogs: Blog[] = [];

    constructor(private blogService: BlogService){}

    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.blogService.$blogPosted.subscribe((blogAction: BlogActionModel) => {
            if(blogAction.action === BlogAction.CREATE){
                this.blogs.push(blogAction.blog);
            }else if(blogAction.action === BlogAction.DELETE){
                //do delete
            }else{
                //do update
            }
        });
    }

}
```